# Node.js using PHP and EJS as template engine, how do I pass and access data from routes to and in template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, node-modules, php-node

How can I access the data in a template?

Below is the code from file *server.js* (main Node.js module):

```
var engine = require('express-ejs-layouts');
app.get('/', router);
app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('php', phpnode);
app.set('view engine', 'php');
```

#### File *routes.js*

```
// Initialize views
router.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.render('index', {data : 'jobDataVal'});
})
```

#### File *index.php* (template file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <?php include_once('header_scripts.php'); ?>
   </head>
   <body>
     <?php echo $data; ?>
     <%= data %>
     <?php include_once('footer_scripts.php');?>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to access a data variable from routes in the template, but the value is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= $data ?>
```

That is using PHP syntax.